# expected ',' or '...' before '&=' token (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, compiler-construction

I am trying to learn c++ and I have come across an exercise that is giving me quite a bit of trouble.
The compiler is giving me a number of errors, in particular the following:

```
expected ',' or '...' before '&=' token
         Book(int=0, const string&=" ", const string&=" ", int=0, const string&=" ", double=0.0);
```

Could you help me?
I enclose my code.

```
//Book.h This is the base class

#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Date.h"
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::invalid_argument;
using std::out_of_range;
using std::vector;
using std::sort;

class Book{
    public:    
        //Costruttore
        Book(int=0, const string&=" ", const string&=" ", int=0, const string&=" ", double=0.0);
        virtual ~Book()=default;
        //Funzioni Set
        void setId(int);
        void setAuthors(const string&);
        void setTitle(const string&);
        void setYear(int);
        void setPosition(const string&);
        void setValue(double);
        //Funzioni Get
        int getId() const;
        string getAuthors() const;
        string getTitle() const;
        int getYear() const;
        string getPosition() const;
        double getValue() const;
        //Funzione Stampa
        virtual void print() const;
        //Overloading di operatori utili per l'ordinamento
        bool operator<(const Book& sec) const;

    protected:
        int book_id, year;
        string authors, title, position;
        double value;

};

#endif

//Book.cpp, implementation of Book.h
#include "Book.h"

//Costruttore
Book::Book(int id, const string& aut, const string& t, int y, const string& pos, double val){
    setId(id);
    setAuthors(aut);
    setTitle(t);
    setYear(y);
    setPosition(pos);
    setValue(val);
}

//Funzioni SET
void Book::setId(int id){
    book_id=id;
}

void Book::setAuthors(const string& aut){
    authors=aut;
}

void Book::setTitle(const string& t){
    title=t;
}

void Book::setYear(int y){
    if(y<=0 || y>2022)
        out_of_range("L'anno deve essere compreso fra 1 e 2022");
    else
        year=y;
}

void Book::setPosition(const string& pos){
    position=pos;
}

void Book::setValue(double val){
    if(val<0)
        out_of_range("Il valore deve essere maggiore o uguale a 0.");
    else
        value=val;
}

//Funzioni GET
int Book::getId() const{
    return this->book_id;
}

string Book::getAuthors() const{
    return this->authors;
}

string Book::getTitle() const{
    return this->title;
}

int Book::getYear() const{
    return this->year;
}

string Book::getPosition() const{
    return this->position;
}

double Book::getValue() const{
    return this->value;
}

//Funzione STAMPA
void Book::print() const{
    cout<<"Nome Libro: "<<getTitle()<<
    "\nAutori: "<<getAuthors()<<
    "\nID: "<<getId()<<
    "\nAnno di pubblicazione: "<<getYear()<<
    "\nPosizione in libreria: "<<getPosition()<<
    "\nValore: "<<getValue()<<"$"<<endl;
}

/*
Overloading <
La traccia ci chiede di ordinare per autore, se l'autore
coincide allora bisogna ordinare per anno di pubblicazione.
*/
bool Book::operator<(const Book& sec) const{
    if(authors==sec.authors) return this->year<sec.year;
    else return this->authors<sec.authors;
}


//Borrow.h This is the derived class
#ifndef BORROW_H
#define BORROW_H
#include "Book.h"


class Borrow : public Book{
    public:
        //Dovrà avere due costruttori, uno con data di restituzione standard (30 giorni dopo la data di prestito)...
        Borrow(int, const string&, const string&, int, const string&, double, const Date&);
        virtual ~Borrow()=default;
        //Funzioni SET
        void setDueDate(const Date&);
        //Funzioni GET
        Date getDueDate() const;

        //...L'altro con data di resituzione diversa
        //Borrow(const Book&, Date, Date);
        //Operatore < per l'ordinamento
        //bool operator<(const Borrow&) const;
        //Funzione per la stampa, sarà un override poiché è già presente nella classe base

        virtual void print() const override;

    protected:
        Date collectDate; //Giorno in cui il libro viene preso in prestito
        Date dueDate;     //Giorno in cui il libro deve essere restituito
};

//Borrow.cpp
#include "Borrow.h"

Borrow::Borrow(int id, const string& aut, const string& t, int y, const string& pos, double val, const Date& dat){
    collectDate=dat;
    setDueDate(dat);
}

void Borrow::setDueDate(const Date& dat){
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        dat++;
    }
    dueDate=dat;
}
/*
Borrow::Borrow(const Book& b, Date datOne, Date datTwo){

    collectDate=datOne;
    dueDate=datTwo;
}
*/

void Borrow::print() const{
    
    cout<<"Preso in prestito il: "<<collectDate<<endl;
    cout<<"Da restituire il: "<<getDueDate()<<endl;
}

Date Borrow::getDueDate() const{
    return dueDate;
}

//Makefile
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-std=c++11
DEPS= Book.h Borrow.h Date.h
OBJ= Book.o Borrow.o Date.o main.o

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
esegui: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
clean: $(OBJ)
    rm -f *.exe *.o

//Compiler error
In file included from Book.cpp:1:0:
Book.h:24:33: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&=' token
         Book(int=0, const string&=" ", const string&=" ", int=0, const string&=" ", double=0.0);
                                 ^~
Book.h:24:9: error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of 'Book::Book(int, std::__cxx11::string)'
         Book(int=0, const string&=" ", const string&=" ", int=0, const string&=" ", double=0.0);
         ^~~~
Book.cpp:4:1: error: prototype for 'Book::Book(int, const string&, const string&, int, const string&, double)' does not match any in class 'Book'
 Book::Book(int id, const string& aut, const string& t, int y, const string& pos, double val){
 ^~~~
In file included from Book.cpp:1:0:
Book.h:21:7: error: candidates are: Book::Book(const Book&)
 class Book{
       ^~~~
Book.h:24:9: error:                 Book::Book(int, std::__cxx11::string)
         Book(int=0, const string&=" ", const string&=" ", int=0, const string&=" ", double=0.0);
         ^~~~
make: *** [Book.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Remove all the default parameter values for the `Book` declaration at `Book.h`. Use member initialization instead.

Comment: You could remove at least 98% of that code and still show the problem. Don't waste peoples' time with noise.

Answer (score 2):

You must add a space between `&` and `=` to have it interpreted as two tokens. Otherwise it is interpreted as a single `&=` token and the `&=` token doesn't make any sense in that position. It is used only in expressions as the bitwise-and compound assignment.

Whitespace can generally be left out, but that is only true as long as there is enough whitespace to separate tokens, which would otherwise be ambiguous. That is more obvious for example if two identifiers follow one-after-another, which would be interpreted as one identifier without at least one space between them. (And even after that there are a few exceptions.)

Comment: Thanks!! but now there are too many errors :/

Comment: @CastreseBasile Well, one problem per question. This should solve the immediate one you asked about. Feel free to create more questions, but always provide a [mre] for the issue, not your full code as you did here, and first spent some time to make sure that there isn't already an answer somewhere on this site. See [ask].

Comment: Consider using *global search and replace* if there are too many similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is used the compound assignment operator

```
const string&=" "
            ^^
```

You need to separate these two tokens at least like

```
const string& =" "
```

Or it is better to write

```
const string & = " "
```